# image width is zero in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

this displays fine in FF,Opera, IE9, but in Chrome, the images don't display due to a zero width on images
any idea why?

http://drbrent.sideradesign.com/photo-gallery/

thanks

Comment: It is working for me in Chrome (I have the Chrome beta, 12.0.742.30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing following styling fixes the issue

```
/* style.css:949 */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ok : doc says "Defines the maximum width in percent of the containing block", so as the containing <a> tag didn't have a width, it wasn't showing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it's because you didn't specify px or em. upon inspection with chrome, it tells me that the image is 0x313 and your style says width="137"; height="313";
should be width"137px" height="313px". That's one of the problem. If that doesn't fix it, might be something else.

Edit: Like @jibiel said, it's your img{max-width:100%;}